# Tests timeout on github but finish locally

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytest, github-actions

I have `pytest` unit tests in my python project, which I run on every push to github. Lately, the tests on (windows, python 3.9) and (windows, python 3.10) don't finish even after 6h, and I'm trying to figure out, why.

For context:

- It's not just the python version, as python 3.9 and 3.10 finish on mac and linux. Also, it's not just the windows version, as windows finishes with python 3.8. And they all finish in at most ~1h.

  [image]
- Locally, windows with python 3.9 finishes in <1h. This is also the case in a fresh conda virtual environment.

  [image]
- Even pushing a version of the code which previously caused no problems, does now run into the timeout. So I assume it's not something in my code, but rather in a dependency or in the way github actions are setup (?). I don't know enough about this to make an informed assessment.

Any help in debugging this is greatly appreciated.

[Here](https://github.com/rwijtvliet/portfolyo) is the project and [here](https://github.com/rwijtvliet/portfolyo/actions/runs/3161047709) is an example of the test results.

---

Edit: I've taken a look at install log in each of the 3 windows cases and compared them. Here are the differences:

```
{'missing': {'typing-extensions': {'38': '4.4.0', '39': '4.4.0'}},
 'different': {'setuptools': {'38': '56.0.0', '39': '58.1.0', '310': '63.2.0'}}}
```

I'd be surprised if `setuptools` is the culprit - isn't it only used while installing the package? Also, 3.9 on mac and 3.9 on ubuntu use the same `58.1.0` version as 3.9 on windows.

Here are all versions, should it be of any help:

```
            {'colorama': {38: '0.4.5', 39: '0.4.5', 310: '0.4.5'},
             'setuptools': {38: '56.0.0', 39: '58.1.0', 310: '63.2.0'},
             'openpyxl': {38: '3.0.10', 39: '3.0.10', 310: '3.0.10'},
             'tomli': {38: '2.0.1', 39: '2.0.1', 310: '2.0.1'},
             'packaging': {38: '21.3', 39: '21.3', 310: '21.3'},
             'et-xmlfile': {38: '1.1.0', 39: '1.1.0', 310: '1.1.0'},
             'pyparsing': {38: '3.0.9', 39: '3.0.9', 310: '3.0.9'},
             'contourpy': {38: '1.0.5', 39: '1.0.5', 310: '1.0.5'},
             'cycler': {38: '0.11.0', 39: '0.11.0', 310: '0.11.0'},
             'fonttools': {38: '4.37.4', 39: '4.37.4', 310: '4.37.4'},
             'kiwisolver': {38: '1.4.4', 39: '1.4.4', 310: '1.4.4'},
             'matplotlib': {38: '3.6.1', 39: '3.6.1', 310: '3.6.1'},
             'numpy': {38: '1.23.4', 39: '1.23.4', 310: '1.23.4'},
             'pandas': {38: '1.5.1', 39: '1.5.1', 310: '1.5.1'},
             'pillow': {38: '9.2.0', 39: '9.2.0', 310: '9.2.0'},
             'pint': {38: '0.19.2', 39: '0.19.2', 310: '0.19.2'},
             'pint-pandas': {38: '0.2', 39: '0.2', 310: '0.2'},
             'portfolyo': {38: '0+untagged.1.g7a9e60b',
              39: '0+untagged.1.g7a9e60b',
              310: '0+untagged.1.g7a9e60b'},
             'python-dateutil': {38: '2.8.2', 39: '2.8.2', 310: '2.8.2'},
             'pytz': {38: '2022.5', 39: '2022.5', 310: '2022.5'},
             'six': {38: '1.16.0', 39: '1.16.0', 310: '1.16.0'},
             'black': {38: '22.10.0', 39: '22.10.0', 310: '22.10.0'},
             'cfgv': {38: '3.3.1', 39: '3.3.1', 310: '3.3.1'},
             'click': {38: '8.1.3', 39: '8.1.3', 310: '8.1.3'},
             'distlib': {38: '0.3.6', 39: '0.3.6', 310: '0.3.6'},
             'filelock': {38: '3.8.0', 39: '3.8.0', 310: '3.8.0'},
             'flake8': {38: '5.0.4', 39: '5.0.4', 310: '5.0.4'},
             'identify': {38: '2.5.6', 39: '2.5.6', 310: '2.5.6'},
             'mccabe': {38: '0.7.0', 39: '0.7.0', 310: '0.7.0'},
             'mypy-extensions': {38: '0.4.3', 39: '0.4.3', 310: '0.4.3'},
             'nodeenv': {38: '1.7.0', 39: '1.7.0', 310: '1.7.0'},
             'pathspec': {38: '0.10.1', 39: '0.10.1', 310: '0.10.1'},
             'platformdirs': {38: '2.5.2', 39: '2.5.2', 310: '2.5.2'},
             'pre-commit': {38: '2.20.0', 39: '2.20.0', 310: '2.20.0'},
             'pycodestyle': {38: '2.9.1', 39: '2.9.1', 310: '2.9.1'},
             'pyflakes': {38: '2.5.0', 39: '2.5.0', 310: '2.5.0'},
             'pyyaml': {38: '6.0', 39: '6.0', 310: '6.0'},
             'toml': {38: '0.10.2', 39: '0.10.2', 310: '0.10.2'},
             'typing-extensions': {38: '4.4.0', 39: '4.4.0'},
             'virtualenv': {38: '20.16.5', 39: '20.16.5', 310: '20.16.5'},
             'attrs': {38: '22.1.0', 39: '22.1.0', 310: '22.1.0'},
             'certifi': {38: '2022.9.24', 39: '2022.9.24', 310: '2022.9.24'},
             'charset-normalizer': {38: '2.1.1', 39: '2.1.1', 310: '2.1.1'},
             'codecov': {38: '2.1.12', 39: '2.1.12', 310: '2.1.12'},
             'coverage': {38: '6.5.0', 39: '6.5.0', 310: '6.5.0'},
             'idna': {38: '3.4', 39: '3.4', 310: '3.4'},
             'iniconfig': {38: '1.1.1', 39: '1.1.1', 310: '1.1.1'},
             'pluggy': {38: '1.0.0', 39: '1.0.0', 310: '1.0.0'},
             'py': {38: '1.11.0', 39: '1.11.0', 310: '1.11.0'},
             'pytest': {38: '7.1.3', 39: '7.1.3', 310: '7.1.3'},
             'pytest-cov': {38: '4.0.0', 39: '4.0.0', 310: '4.0.0'},
             'requests': {38: '2.28.1', 39: '2.28.1', 310: '2.28.1'},
             'urllib3': {38: '1.26.1', 39: '1.26.1', 310: '1.26.1'}}
```

---

Edit: I have now also compared the final passing commit to the first timing-out commit (of the same code base and both python 3.9 on windows). There are the following differences:

```
{'missing': {'contourpy': {'39firstnok': '1.0.5'}},
 'different': {'fonttools': {'39finalok': '4.37.1', '39firstnok': '4.37.4'},
  'matplotlib': {'39finalok': '3.5.3', '39firstnok': '3.6.0'},
  'numpy': {'39finalok': '1.23.2', '39firstnok': '1.23.3'},
  'pandas': {'39finalok': '1.4.4', '39firstnok': '1.5.0'},
  'pytz': {'39finalok': '2022.2.1', '39firstnok': '2022.4'},
  'identify': {'39finalok': '2.5.5', '39firstnok': '2.5.6'},
  'virtualenv': {'39finalok': '20.16.4', '39firstnok': '20.16.5'},
  'certifi': {'39finalok': '2022.6.15', '39firstnok': '2022.9.24'},
  'coverage': {'39finalok': '6.4.4', '39firstnok': '6.5.0'},
  'idna': {'39finalok': '3.3', '39firstnok': '3.4'},
  'pytest-cov': {'39finalok': '3.0.0', '39firstnok': '4.0.0'},
  'urllib3': {'39finalok': '1.26.1', '39firstnok': '1.26.12'}}}
```

I'd like to find out, if one of these version is the culprit. I guess I'll have to start by pinning the version of each one and see what happens if I unpin them one by one.

Here is a list of all the packages and their versions:

```
            {'colorama': {'39finalok': '0.4.5', '39firstnok': '0.4.5'},
             'packaging': {'39finalok': '21.3', '39firstnok': '21.3'},
             'pyparsing': {'39finalok': '3.0.9', '39firstnok': '3.0.9'},
             'click': {'39finalok': '8.1.3', '39firstnok': '8.1.3'},
             'setuptools': {'39finalok': '58.1.0', '39firstnok': '58.1.0'},
             'tomli': {'39finalok': '2.0.1', '39firstnok': '2.0.1'},
             'cycler': {'39finalok': '0.11.0', '39firstnok': '0.11.0'},
             'fonttools': {'39finalok': '4.37.1', '39firstnok': '4.37.4'},
             'kiwisolver': {'39finalok': '1.4.4', '39firstnok': '1.4.4'},
             'matplotlib': {'39finalok': '3.5.3', '39firstnok': '3.6.0'},
             'numpy': {'39finalok': '1.23.2', '39firstnok': '1.23.3'},
             'pandas': {'39finalok': '1.4.4', '39firstnok': '1.5.0'},
             'pillow': {'39finalok': '9.2.0', '39firstnok': '9.2.0'},
             'pint': {'39finalok': '0.19.2', '39firstnok': '0.19.2'},
             'pint-pandas': {'39finalok': '0.2', '39firstnok': '0.2'},
             'portfolyo': {'39finalok': '0+untagged.1.g739f383',
              '39firstnok': '0+untagged.1.g739f383'},
             'python-dateutil': {'39finalok': '2.8.2', '39firstnok': '2.8.2'},
             'pytz': {'39finalok': '2022.2.1', '39firstnok': '2022.4'},
             'six': {'39finalok': '1.16.0', '39firstnok': '1.16.0'},
             'black': {'39finalok': '22.8.0', '39firstnok': '22.8.0'},
             'cfgv': {'39finalok': '3.3.1', '39firstnok': '3.3.1'},
             'distlib': {'39finalok': '0.3.6', '39firstnok': '0.3.6'},
             'et-xmlfile': {'39finalok': '1.1.0', '39firstnok': '1.1.0'},
             'filelock': {'39finalok': '3.8.0', '39firstnok': '3.8.0'},
             'flake8': {'39finalok': '5.0.4', '39firstnok': '5.0.4'},
             'identify': {'39finalok': '2.5.5', '39firstnok': '2.5.6'},
             'mccabe': {'39finalok': '0.7.0', '39firstnok': '0.7.0'},
             'mypy-extensions': {'39finalok': '0.4.3', '39firstnok': '0.4.3'},
             'nodeenv': {'39finalok': '1.7.0', '39firstnok': '1.7.0'},
             'openpyxl': {'39finalok': '3.0.10', '39firstnok': '3.0.10'},
             'pathspec': {'39finalok': '0.10.1', '39firstnok': '0.10.1'},
             'platformdirs': {'39finalok': '2.5.2', '39firstnok': '2.5.2'},
             'pre-commit': {'39finalok': '2.20.0', '39firstnok': '2.20.0'},
             'pycodestyle': {'39finalok': '2.9.1', '39firstnok': '2.9.1'},
             'pyflakes': {'39finalok': '2.5.0', '39firstnok': '2.5.0'},
             'pyyaml': {'39finalok': '6.0', '39firstnok': '6.0'},
             'toml': {'39finalok': '0.10.2', '39firstnok': '0.10.2'},
             'typing-extensions': {'39finalok': '4.3.0',
              '39firstnok': '4.3.0'},
             'virtualenv': {'39finalok': '20.16.4', '39firstnok': '20.16.5'},
             'attrs': {'39finalok': '22.1.0', '39firstnok': '22.1.0'},
             'certifi': {'39finalok': '2022.6.15', '39firstnok': '2022.9.24'},
             'charset-normalizer': {'39finalok': '2.1.1',
              '39firstnok': '2.1.1'},
             'codecov': {'39finalok': '2.1.12', '39firstnok': '2.1.12'},
             'coverage': {'39finalok': '6.4.4', '39firstnok': '6.5.0'},
             'idna': {'39finalok': '3.3', '39firstnok': '3.4'},
             'iniconfig': {'39finalok': '1.1.1', '39firstnok': '1.1.1'},
             'pluggy': {'39finalok': '1.0.0', '39firstnok': '1.0.0'},
             'py': {'39finalok': '1.11.0', '39firstnok': '1.11.0'},
             'pytest': {'39finalok': '7.1.3', '39firstnok': '7.1.3'},
             'pytest-cov': {'39finalok': '3.0.0', '39firstnok': '4.0.0'},
             'requests': {'39finalok': '2.28.1', '39firstnok': '2.28.1'},
             'urllib3': {'39finalok': '1.26.1', '39firstnok': '1.26.12'},
             'contourpy': {'39firstnok': '1.0.5'}}
```

---

Edit: Breakthrough! After pinning `numpy`, `pandas` and `matplotlib` to the following versions, the tests finished also on windows:

```
numpy==1.23.2
pandas==1.4.4
matplotlib==3.5.3
```

[image]

I assume this means that there is a corner-case bug in one of these packages. Or in how I use them. I'll stick to pinning these versions for now, and will revisit in a few months by unpinning.

Comment: You could try using a lib like [pytest-split](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-split/) to run some of those tests in parallel.

Comment: I would add `--durations=0` to the pytest command line to show the test times in the output. Maybe there are some tests that are extraordinary slow, or maybe the last test just hangs, but this may give you an idea. Though it may not print this if the test is timed out... Probably indeed have to split the test first.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As the tests normally take 45 min to 1 h, and now time out after 6h, I don't think it's a resources issue. I assume one of the tests hangs up in some edge case, and I'm trying to figure out, which one. Also, I'm trying to understand, how it's possible, that the tests complete locally but not in the Github VM

Comment: Noone? If there is more information that could be useful, please let me know and I'll happily provide It. I'd there a way to see in guthub which package versions were installed for the dependencies?

Comment: You could use [pytest-timeouts](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeouts/) to set some reasonable timeout per test - this way longer tests will be aborted, and you can see which one(s) in the output.

Comment: Thanks @MrBeanBremen for the suggestion. It's a good idea in principle, but that plugin only works on linux, and the tests run on windows. I could add some kind of logging, but there is no way to access these on github's VMs. I'm thinking the only option I have is to comment out tests, push, wait for the results, and that way narrow down which tests cause the issue. No fun though, as it's 6h per pop

Comment: Actually it was my mistake - I meant [pytest-timeout](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-timeout/), which is also available under Windows (though I haven't used it myself).

Comment: @ElRudi have you had any luck in resolving this issue? If so any insight into what happened would be amazing. I'm facing something similar with Github actions. Albeit on an Ubuntu machine.

Comment: Unfortunately not... I opened a bounty to hopefully get it resolved.

Comment: @ChadLamb, see my updated question. I found the immediate cause and a solution. But not the ultimate cause.

Comment: Thanks @ElRudi, the project I am on, we could luckily remove some tests that we don't need to run anymore. Which happened to be the ones causing the issue. Matplotlib and Numpy are in the project, so I will keep that in mind if we run into it again. Glad you resolved the problem for now.